# Spring Boot OneToOne save(): A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I think I'm driving extremely simple case of Spring Boot and Hibernate usage. My intention is to store information about `Cyclist` class inside `User` class in `OneToOne` relationship.

During registration, instance of `User` class is created and stored into database. When user refreshes `/home` page, clicks counter is increased and entity is saved (updated). This is a simple test of sessions and updating the database, which works:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired private UserSession userSession;
    @Autowired private UserDAO userDAO;

    @GetMapping
    public String home(Model model) {
        User user = userSession.getUser();
        user.setClicks(user.getClicks() + 1);

        userDAO.save(user); 

        return "home";
    }
}
```

The problem comes when user fulfils `/createCyclist` form:

```
@Autowired private UserDAO userDAO;

@PostMapping
public String createCyclist(@Valid CyclistCreationForm cyclistCreationForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    /* Form handling */
    User user = userSession.getUser();

    Cyclist cyclist = new Cyclist(user, cyclistCreationForm.getHeight(), cyclistCreationForm.getGender());
    user.setCyclist(cyclist);

    userDAO.save(user);
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

Above one executes without an exception, but forces user browser to load /home page. From this moment, calling `userDAO.save(user)` in `/home` produces an exception:

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session [<package>.Cyclist#1]
```

The rest of exception is useless stacktrace.

This is how I designed `Cyclist` class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="cyclists")
public class Cyclist {
    private int id;
    private User user;

    /* Some float fields */

    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

And `User` class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private Integer uid;
    private String name;
    private String password;

    private Cyclist cyclist;

    private int clicks;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    public Integer getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    @NotNull
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @NotNull
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Cyclist getCyclist() {
        return cyclist;
    }

    public int getClicks() {
        return clicks;
    }
}
```

I read many problems posted on SO/google, but couldn't fit my issue.

User and Cyclist DAO are `CrudRepository` implementations. I'm using lombok to generate boilerplate code. I was a little aware of lombok's `@Data` in case of `hashCode` and `toString` generation so I tried using only `@Getter` and `@Setter`. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You should considerer using `userDao.merge(user)`, and perhaps write an `upsert(...)` method. By the way don't make an insert at each refresh, your server will be overloaded.

Comment: Each refresh of `/home` page produces one select and one update query right now. And it seems that Spring's `CrudRepository` doesn't provide other methods than `save()`

Comment: Your DAO must provide an `merge` even `update` method, by convention `save` mean "save new entity" and `merge` mean "update an existing entity".

Comment: I have investigated Spring's DAO `save()` and it checks if information exists and if so, it uses merge, otherwise persist

Comment: In my case, `merge` from `javax.persistence.EntityManager` interface is used.

Comment: Try things like  `@JoinColumn(name = "id")` or ` @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id", orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = Cyclist.class)` it might help.

Comment: `@JoinColumn` only renames the column used for joining. Using `@OneToMany` seems to be a bad solution for me..

Comment: Sorry bad copy/past I would tell you `@OneToOne`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was caused by `@MapsId`. Simple `@OneToOne` mapping requires only:

User.java:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Cyclist getCyclist() {
    return cyclist;
}
```

Cyclist.java:

```
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

Then, you persist everything by calling `setCyclist` on user and `userDao.save(user)`.

In past I wanted to make Cyclist's primary key be also foreign key equal to User's uid.. This wouldn't require additional field in `users` table. So I tried with @MapsId and forget about it. I'll try to achieve bidirectional shared primary key in a way that this tutorial describe:

http://websystique.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-bidirectional-with-shared-primary-key-annotation-example/

EDIT: I did as I said. One-to-one mapping with Cyclist's primary key same as User's id:

User.java:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Cyclist getCyclist() {
    return cyclist;
}
```

Cyclist.java:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
@GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign",parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="user"))
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you! I hope :)

When it is Bidirectional.

If the child class is sharing the Parent's class primary key, Then Parent class primary key and child class primary key must be same while saving or updating.
Otherwise you will get below exception!

> **`different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session`**

> **SOLUTION**

If you want update then you have to set **same primary key** to `parent` and `child` classes!
**Don't forget to review mapped entities whether they are having same primary key or not before you hitting the save().** If not you may need to do like below. Get the key/id from parent entity and set it parent's child entity

```
@Autowired
ParentRepo parentRepo;
 
@Autowired
ChildRepo childRepo;
 
 
public Parent saveorupdateJPAStyle(Parent parent) {

        parent.getChild().setId(parent.getId()); // on the this ID update should happen to the child when I save the Parent**(important)** 
        parent.getChild().setName("Prince007"); //did some update on child
        parent.getChild().setParent(parent); // setting up the parent to child because it's uni directional
 
        parent.setStatus("saved"); // did some update on parent 
     
      return parentRepo.save(parent);
    }
```

Thanks!!!